# error encountered in building vein-lte 1.3

Tags: omnet++, veins, lte, veins-lte

When I run the 'make' command at the terminal window to build vein-lte 1.3, I **encounter a fatal error** at **applications/commons/ApplicationBase.cc: 18:0**.

There seem to be an issue with including the header **Operationalbase.h** in **ApplicationBase.h**. 
It complains that there is no such file or directory. The error is originating from the inet folder. 
I really need help with resolving this. 
Cheers.