# Error(s) in building Veins-LTE: OperationalBase.h not found

Tags: makefile, omnet++, veins

I am trying to build Veins-LTE 1.3, which includes **inet**, **simulte** and **veins** for LTE-based vehicular networks simulations. 
By following the README, I get into the root package and write:

```
make makefiles    //this creates the required Makefile in inet, veins and simulte
make
```

This last command, however, results into a fatal error in building **inet**:

```
In file included from applications/common/ApplicationBase.h:21:10: 
fatal error: 'OperationalBase.h': file not found
```

By opening the file 'inet/src/applications/common/ApplicationBase.h', I immediately realize that the problem lies in the inclusion of the 'OperationalBase.h', which, as a matter of fact, **is not present in the same directory**. Instead, it can be found in the 'inet/src/base/' directory.

Omnet++ : 5.2.
Veins-LTE: inet 2.3.0,   veins 2.1bis,  simulte 0.9.1 
SUMO: 0.30.0 (if this could be relevant)
Environment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 - amd64

I am perfectly conscious that a similar question already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459603/error-encountered-in-building-vein-lte-1-3), but it has not received answers nor comments since last August, so..

**WHAT I TRIED TO DO:**

1. My first action was simply to change the path in the include statement so that to point to the right folder: `#include "../../base/OperationalBase.h"`; this actually shifts the problem elsewhere, since **all** the other source files in the 'inet' framework inside the veins-lte package do not include the full paths of the required header files (i.e., they seem to  assume all the .h files are inside the same directory). Moreover, the `omnetpp` methods are not recognized, since no `using namespace omnetpp` is present.

   2. I had a look at 'inet/Makefile' file; in particular, after changing to the 'src/' folder, the `opp_makemake` command comes with the following options:

`opp_makemake -f --deep --make-so -o inet -O out -pINET -
Xapplications/voipstream -Xtransport/tcp_lwip -Xtransport/tcp_nsc -
DWITH_TCP_COMMON` .... and other stuff sounding like -DWITH_

As per the `opp_makemake` documentation ([opp_makemake](https://github.com/shigeya/omnetpp/blob/master/src/utils/opp_makemake)), the `--deep` option should cater for deep includes. Does it mean that the full (or relative to `src/`) path of the `.h` file to be included is not required? The only source folders that are excluded seem to be `transport/tcp_lwip`, `applications/voipstream`, `transport/tcp_nsc`.

So, should I modify all source files by writing the full/relative path of the included files?
Is there a better, smarter, more centralized way to achieve this goal, maybe by modifying something in the `inet/Makefile` file?
Am I missing something very obvious?

Thank You

**WHAT I AM ABLE TO DO:**

- Successfully run the Omnet++ TicToc examples;
- Successfully run the veins RSU Example (by using the stand-alone veins 
  release)
- Successfully run basic SUMO examples.

Comment: The installation instructions http://veins-lte.car2x.org/installation/ mention much older versions of OMNeT++ (version 4.6) and SUMO (version 0.25.0). Maybe this is a simple case of older OMNeT++ versions building other Makefiles

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I will try to build an older version of OMNET++

Comment: @ChristophSommer has a point. For newer versions, various - not yet released - adaptions to the Veins LTE source code and the build scripts are necessary.